# Running rails inclusion validation only if presence passes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want to have validate the presence of a field first and return one error message if there is no value for the field. Then assuming that this presence validation passes, I want to run an inclusion validation.

Right now I have :

```
validates :segment_type, presence: true, inclusion: { in: SEGMENT_TYPES }
```

I have tried splitting this up into two separate validations as follows:

```
validates :segment_type, presence: true
validates :segment_type, inclusion: { in: SEGMENT_TYPES }
```

But the problem is for both of the attempts above, when no value is included in the `segment_type` field, I get error messages for both responses:

```
Segment type can't be blank
Segment type is not included in the list
```

In this case, I would just want "Segment type can't be blank" and not the second message.

Is there any way that I can tell rails to do this conditional validation and give me the desired waterfall of error messages without me having to define a custom function, say `segment_type_presence_and_inclusion_check` that checks these conditions in sequence and calling it with `validate :segment_type_presence_and_inclusion_check`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pass in an `if` inside the `inclusion` option to check for the presence

```
validates :segment_type,
  presence: true,
  inclusion: { in: SEGMENT_TYPES, if: :segment_type_present? }

private

def segment_type_present?
  segment_type.present?
end
```

you can also use a `proc`

```
inclusion: { in: SEGMENT_TYPES, if: proc { |x| x.segment_type.present? } }
```

Comment: Does this only work with `inclusion:`? I cannot seem to replace `inclusion` with a custom validator and so am using @michael-discenza 's method below, but feels it should be possible by calling `validates:` on the model just the once (rather than twice).

Comment: no it should work with other validation helpers. what's the code you're trying to fix?

Comment: `validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }`
`validates :title, generate_url: true, if: proc { |p| p.title.present? && p.title.length <= 255 }`

I then have a `GenerateUrlValidator` in `app/validators`.

Comment: ahh.. hmm not sure. never had a chance to do this like this before.  Have you already tried `validates :title, generate_url: { if: proc { |p| p.title.present? } }`

Comment: Rails generates a method with the name of your attribute + question mark to test the presence of the value. So you can simply do `segment_type?` which does the same as `segment_type.present?`

Comment: Also, you can directly do `validates :segment_type, inclusion: { in: SOME_LIST, allow_nil: true }` (see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil)

Comment: @MrYoshiji thanks. aware of that but don't really want to move away from the main question.  it's easier to show that you can use a method if you're not only checking the presence in the method.

Answer (score 14):

You should also be able to use `allow_blank` on the inclusion validation

```
validates :segment_type,
          presence: true,
          inclusion: { in: SEGMENT_TYPES, allow_blank: true }
```

Comment: this is simpler and more elegant than the marked answer. FYI see also `allow_nil: true`. i think these are the relevant docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates

Comment: The `presence: true` is not necessary here since. Also, `allow_blank` is now supposed to be *outside* of the `inclusion: {}` options hash. (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-nil)

Comment: In fact SEGMENT_TYPES seems like an integer field used for enumeration, therefore allow_nil is the option to use, instad of allow_blank.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that this works as well.

```
validates :segment_type, presence: true
validates :segment_type, inclusion: { in: SEGMENT_TYPES }, if: "segment_type.present?"
```